# DropBox keeps giving me 403 error after my application is authenticated ios sdk

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I get this warning message after I login to Dropbox:

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/fileops/delete - (403) Parameter not found: oauth_token
```

However, if I restart my app, the warning doesn't pop up again. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: This error should indicate that you're somehow trying to make an API call without the 'oauth_token' parameter, which holds the access token key. Have you implemented the auth flow as shown in the tutorial ( https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios )? The issue might be that you're making the DBRestClient without actually having an account linked, or maybe that there are keychain issues preventing the stored access token from being retrieved.